# I cannot find app service name of my current subscription

Tags: reactjs, azure, devops

I already create app service from my Azure Subscription but I can't find it when I tried to create new release pipeline. [Cannot find app service from current Subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gukR.png)

Answer (score 0):

As i tried to create a release pipeline for my app service and i can able to see my application from App service drop down box.
Please make sure that the created app services present in same subscription which you select .

or, Try to refresh the  `App service name drop down`  as shown in below

[image]

For more information please refer this  [Build your app with Azure Pipelines| MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows,yaml#build-your-app-with-azure-pipelines) & [App service name not visible on configuring release definition page.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/app-service-name-not-visible-on-configuring-releas/122321?viewtype=all)